# Unable To Change SeriesChartType Dynamically in MS Chart Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

I am using the MS Chart control (version 3.5.0).
I have added it by using the designer (drag and drop). I removed the default "Series1" from the Properties -> Series -> Collection so that the chart contains no data.

I am adding the data at runtime based on a canned query to a SQLite DB. Like so:

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM ageLength ORDER BY month"
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQL)
Dim SqLiteConnection1 As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection()
SqLiteConnection1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Data\UserData.db3;"
cmd.Connection = SqLiteConnection1
Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds, "ageLength")

Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
Dim Series2 As Series = New Series()
Series1.Name = "Pcnt2nd"
Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
Series2.Name = "Pcnt98th"
Series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
Chart1.Series.Add("Pcnt2nd")
Chart1.Series.Add("Pcnt98th")

Chart1.Series("Pcnt2nd").XValueMember = "month"
Chart1.Series("Pcnt2nd").YValueMembers = "Pcnt2nd"
Chart1.Series("Pcnt98th").XValueMember = "month"
Chart1.Series("Pcnt98th").YValueMembers = "Pcnt98th"
Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

The data is displayed on the Chart, however, it is a Bar type graph. I set it to use the Spline type for both series. I am not sure what I missed. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a lot more messing around I found the solution:
I remove these 2 lines:

```
Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
Series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
```

And then I add these 2 lines:

```
Chart1.Series("Pcnt2nd").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
Chart1.Series("Pcnt98th").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
```

Not sure why that is...but there you have it.